# Aggregating a data.frame with NAs using data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate, na

I have a large `data.frame` with a `character` column and several numeric columns that contain `NA`'s.

Here are a few example rows:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep("A",3),v1=c(NA,1,NA),v2=c(2,5,2),v3=c(NA,NA,NA),V4=c(0,0,0),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Since `df$id` repeats I want to `aggregate` `df` by `df$id`, and apply `sum` to all the other columns.

I did this:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x,na.rm=T)),by=.(id)]
```

and am getting this:

```
   id v1 v2 v3 V4
1:  A  1  9  0  0
```

So column `v3` is all `NA`'s in `df` and hence gets a value of `0`, which poses a problem for me since in such case I'd like to keep the `NA` value but in all other cases (where the aggregation is over a mix of numerics and `NA`'s, obviously I'd like to remove the `NA`'s otherwise the sum will be `NA`). As the example shows (`df$v4`) I have columns which are all `0`, therefore I can't simply replace all `0`'s with `NA`'s from the aggregated `data.frame`.

In other words this is my desired outcome:

```
   id v1 v2 v3 V4
1:  A  1  9  NA 0
```

Any idea how to get `data.table`'s `.SD` aggregation to achieve this?

Comment: not a `data.table` problem: `sum(c(NA, NA, NA), na.rm=TRUE)` returns `0` because *"the sum of an empty set is zero, by definition."*

Comment: Write your own function `mySum <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)),NA,sum(x,na.rm=T))),by=.(id)]
id v1 v2 v3 V4
1:  A  1  9 NA  0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this without an `if/else` statement

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)*NA^all(is.na(x))), id]
#   id v1 v2 v3 V4
#1:  A  1  9 NA  0
```